# Showing database time value in timepicker

Tags: php

I want to display results coming from a database in timepicker but it is not displaying anything. Please help. Here is my code:

```
<input type="Time" name="dep_time" id="dep-time" class="form-control"  required="" value="<?php echo $response['dep_time'] ?>">
```

Comment: what's the exact value of `$response['dep_time']`? What if you hardcode a date there - working then?

Comment: It would be helpful for visitors if you let them know the time format picker is expecting and the time format returned in `$response['dep_time']`.

Answer (score 1):

The code looks OK, however, your PHP line is not aptly terminated (using a semicolon). If there are any issues, we will need more information.

```
<input type="Time" name="dep_time" id="dep-time" class="form-control"  required="" value="<?php echo $response['dep_time']; ?>">
```